# Why we use padding for sentences, when RNN can take dynamic sequence of input?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

**While reading the question just consider the left diagram(Folded Image)**

In the figure we are unfolding the RNN, we are passing on output of T time stamp to next T+1 time stamp, which is to same RNN or which is we are sending output of T time stamp back to the same neural network, **so we are looping the process on same neuro/neurons.** Let's consider architecture to be Many-to-one RNN.

So, the length of sentence can be any length, because the network can take any number of inputs (Any number of Time stamps) and just loop passing the previous output to next time stamp. **Then what is the need of padding when network can take any length of sentences and just loop? 

For example:**
1.) He is good boy
2.) Satoshi Nakamoto should get noble prize in economics.

[image]

- In this 2 sentences, The network can take 1st sentence and pass it on to T, T+1, T+2,T+3 time stamps respectively
- In the 2nd Sentence, the network can pass it in to T,T+1,T+2,T+3,T+4,T+5....
  So the network can take any length of sentences to the network (Which is just passing the output of time stamp back to the network for next time stamp). What is the Need for padding sentences, When network is looping?

*I can elaborate question properly, if the above information is not sufficient. Kindly, please let me know if the question is not understood properly*

Answer (score 1):

Padding is needed if we want to train them batch-wise. A batch is a rectangular tensor of fixed size. This does not work with sentences of varying lengths, which is why you can either pad or truncate the sentences to a uniform length (see [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/pad_truncation)).

The padding can either be added to the start or end of the sentences. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07288.pdf) is a paper that compares both methods for a many-to-one task.

Comment: Thanks got it.. But let's say we are not training using batch-wise, individually we are giving to network or let's say Batch size=1 like Stochastic Gradient descent, Then is padding necessary?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to pad them if you only feed a single sentence. The question is how stable the training becomes, but, in theory, it's possible.